# PHP cURL programming

Tags: php, curl

I want to perform a cURL command which i can get youtubes Url of videos in an array printed.
I can't make it work any suggestions please

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init(); 
$search_string = "programming knowledge";
$url = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=$search_string";

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($curl);

preg_match_all("!https://[^\s]*?.com/!",$result,$matches);

print_r($matches);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Just saying "I can't make it work" isn't a helpful problem statement.  What is the desired result of this script?  What is the current/actual result?  If you are getting errors, what are the _exact_ errors?  What debugging have you already done?

Comment: The desired result of this script is to learn PHP programming to initiate http requests in PHP First we load a simple page in a browser and output it. We then load search results at youtube.com using php cURL and match every video in the results and store it in array variable. We then loop through the array containing video urls. Thanks for your reply !!

Comment: That's not what he meant by "desired result". You've explained what this code should be doing: presumably one or more of those parts don't work as expected? Which ones? What goes wrong?

Comment: It looks like the video URLs are just "/watch?v=...." so you'll need a different regexp to find them I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing missing is urlencode...  Whenever some data is being sent in the query part of a url, it is always best to run the variable through it as certain characters (like a space) need to be converted.

Try:

```
$search_string = urlencode("programming knowledge");
```

That will convert the space so the end url is correct: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=programming+knowledge

Comment: `$result = curl_exec($curl);
preg_match_all("!https://[^\s]*?.com/!",$result,$matches);

print_r($matches);`     Ok Thanks!!  I don't get the urls from [https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=programming+knowledge]